# Remove ;; in string

Tags: php, regex

I have string

```
;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic;;Called by the Grave);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic;;Called by the Grave;;Secrets of Dark Magic)
```

I want to remove ;; in here {card}(Secrets of Dark Magic;;Called by the Grave) ( not ;; outside)

Result I want

```
   ;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic;Called by the Grave);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic;Called by the Grave;Secrets of Dark Magic)
```

I tried code below but it remove all ;; in string!

```
$search = ';;';
$string = preg_replace("/($search)/", ";", $string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `preg_replace_callback` here to target all text occurring within parentheses `(...)`.  Then, on each match, do a simple string replacement from `;;` to single `;`.

```php
$input = ";{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic;;Called by the Grave);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic;;Called by the Grave;;Secrets of Dark Magic)";
$output = preg_replace_callback("/\(.*?\)/", function($matches) {
    return str_replace(";;", ";", $matches[0]);
}, $input);
echo $input;
echo "\n";
echo $output;
```

This prints:

> ;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic;;Called by the Grave);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic;;Called by the Grave;;Secrets of Dark Magic)

> ;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic;Called by the Grave);;{card}(Secrets of Dark Magic;Called by the Grave;Secrets of Dark Magic)